# When to use ldap based authentication?

Tags: security, web-applications

I am trying to find pros/cons of using ldap based authentication as opposed to application's internal database based authentication.

### LDAP based

One situation I see is where a second application may directly authenticate against the ldap database created by the first application, using an ldap API.

### Internal database based

In this case, the second application can perhaps do the authentication, if the first application has provided an interface such as a web service

The disadvantage I see that with ldap is that one more software component to manage.  The disadvantage I see with the second case is that one has to write a web service to allow the authentication.

I would like to know what would be a good option, if one application may use another application's user database for authentication.

Comment: Advantages can be ease of implementation and maintainability (versus having to roll your own) and a better user experience (one less set of credentials for users to remember). Disadvantages can include a lack of control and difficulty of support for your users (ie, if you don't also manage the LDAP/AD host). That said, this post is possibly off-topic for StackOverflow as it could be very opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for using LDAP (or rather an implementation of LDAP) is to reuse existing directory infrastructure across an organisation. That is, many companies maintain a directory infrastructure describing their organisational units (OUs) and staff organisation within them - i.e. departments, staff, roles, etc. LDAP provides the interface to this directory service.

By managing your security through LDAP, you're in fact able to use this existing infrastructure and security/ roles information, rather than rolling your own. More significantly, this then maintains a single "id" per user, rather than an id in each system, thus enabling single-sign-on across systems. Also, LDAP supports [SSL and TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).

Rather than thinking of LDAP as having "one more software component to manage" as you said, you should think that rolling your own authentication in fact means you have one more user admin system to manage. That is, you need to build the admin tools to manage it (or do your sysadmins expect to use sqlplus or whatever?) Also, you seem to expect that other apps would use your shiny new authentication database when, they may also think "I'll roll my own".

All that said, it's not unreasonable to write your own security module but SSO is an often-asked-for requirement in large enterprises consisting of multiple systems.